# Issue while restoring the backup dump into MySql Database

Tags: mysql, restore

I want to restore the backup dump with format **backup_dump_file.tar.gz** (size: 15GB) into Local MySql Database.

Steps I tried:
1) I created Local MySql database using create database mysql_db command from mysql command shell
2) When I try to untar & then unzip the file backup_dump_file.tar.gz, I get more than two types of files for a single table. e.g.: If the table name is student then i get student.schema.sql & student.sql SQL text files. Total dump size after untar & unzip reaches to 50.5GB

Such more than 8000 tables & files I get for the entire backup dump file. How can i restore all the mysql files into single database for such large tables.

P.S.: There is no information how mysql database backup was taken in the first place. It was taken by some other team which are not available for communication at all.

Kindly help.

Comment: You said, "I get more than two types of files for a single table"  but in the next sentence, you also said that you get 2 files for one table. Just to be clear, which one is true? You get 2 files per table, one containing the table structure and other containing the data or you get multiple files per table?

Comment: Thank you for looking into my issue. This is just one example. I got some _.sql files also generated in between which I believe as the indexes or some intermediary files. But in most of the scenarios, there are only schema.sql & data_.sql files present. So instead of having a single .sql dump of the entire database, I am getting .sql dumps of each of the tables in the database.